# Environment variables not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I tried using environments variables to configure my rails application in production but I can't let them work.

I exported them in my `~/.bashrc` like this

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my_key
export AWS_REGION=my_region
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my_secret_key
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=my_bucket_name
export S3_HOST_NAME=my_host_name
```

and if I use printenv on my terminal, I can see them.

I access them in my `production.rb` like this

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    s3_host_name: ENV['S3_HOST_NAME'],
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    }
 }
```

With this configuration my application crashes when I open a link with an image, saying that I have to specify a bucket_name

If I save them in a `secrets.yml` and access them like this, it works perfectly

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      storage: :s3,
      s3_region: Rails.application.secrets.s3_region,
      s3_host_name: Rails.application.secrets.s3_host_name,
      bucket: Rails.application.secrets.s3_bucket_name,
      s3_credentials: {
          access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.access_key,
          secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.secret_access_key,
      }
  }
```

When I deploy on heroku and set via dashboard the environments variable works great again, it crash only if I access them via ENV['key'] in my computer

[EDIT] The problem was with ruby mine, I added -ic to the script to start it and I solved the problem. Thanks you all

Comment: Is your application using a different user? Maybe you need to put them in /etc/environment ?

Comment: How do you start your application? In the same terminal where you have environment set, you can run `irb` and there check `puts ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use [DirEnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) or [DotEnv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which both load ENV vars from a file. This is a much more sane approach than cluttering your profile.

Additionally when accessing ENV vars which are non-optional use the ActiveSupport `#fetch` method so that is raises an error if the var is not set:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    s3_host_name: ENV.fetch('S3_HOST_NAME'),
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    }
}
```

This makes it much easier to troubleshoot since you will get an error upon starting the Rails server instead of the app blowing up later when the env var is used.

Comment: Highly recommend the dotenv gem.

Comment: @moveson I have moved over to DirEnv instead. It makes more sense to solve it on the shell level instead of making every project dependent on DotEnv.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting env variables in system wide, I suggest you to make use of Rails [dotenv library](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and put your custom need variables in .env file. So, that we can make the env variable will remain secret to only application not system wide.